# Copying single value from query into NEW column/variable in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql

## Question:

What is the correct syntax to use when selecting a column value into an `UPDATE`/`INSERT` trigger `NEW` variable?

## Details:

Here are the [simplified] tables I am using as well as the query. For the purposes of this example I have chosen something that is recursive, in this case a comment (ie. one can comment on a picture, but also on the comment). At any given time I want to know what picture a comment is commenting on, but I don't want to query the table n times to get to that picture (hence why I am rejecting the [Adjacency List Model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)), so I have a trigger on insert to copy the target picture over.

**PICTURES table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pictures
(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)
```

**COMMENTS table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments
(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   picture_id INT NOT NULL,
   comment_id INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( picture_id ) REFERENCES pictures ( id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( comment_id ) REFERENCES comments ( id )
)
```

**COMMENTS trigger:** Note that `NEW.comment_id` and `NEW.picture_id` are `NOT NULL`, therefore, they default to zero (`FALSE`). In my actual program I have an `XOR` to reject invalid attempts to assign both a picture and a comment id.

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_comments_fer BEFORE INSERT ON comments FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF ( NEW.comment_id )
   THEN
      select NEW.picture_id := picture_id from comments where id = NEW.comment_id;
   END IF;
END
```

I tried including an `@` sign, like so

```
select @NEW.picture_id := picture_id from comments where id = NEW.comment_id;
```

But that also raised a syntax error. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET NEW.picture_id := (SELECT picture_id FROM comments WHERE id = NEW.commend_id);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would happen if `SELECT` returned more than one value (ie. `id` was not `UNIQUE`)? Would the universe implode?

Comment: @puk: You would get an error along the lines of the assignment operator not expecting multiple values... can't remember it verbatim off the top of my head.